# Is there a way to acess specfic text in a <li> in BeatifulSoup without using for loops?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

An example of what i want to scrape:

```
<li class="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms"> 
    <span class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"> 3 </span> 
    <span class="property-card__detail-text js-property-card-detail-text"> Quartos </span> 
</li>
```

How could i acess the first span class **without** using for loops? An example:

```
for i in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 padding10"}):
    print(i["data-price"])
    print(i["data-boat_year"])
```

At first i was creating scraping all the *<li>* tags, the iterating through it, the code of course got very polluted.

Comment: Do you want to access the `<span>` text of only one specific `<li>` element?  Or do you want it for several `<li>` elements?

Comment: Also, those `class` values do not seem to match at all.  The html example has `class="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms"`, but the find_all code has `"class": "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-4 padding10"`

Answer (score 0):

From the short example is hard to tell exactly what you want to select, buy you can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<li class="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms">
    <span class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"> 3 </span>
    <span class="property-card__detail-text js-property-card-detail-text"> Quartos </span>
</li>

<li class="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms">
    <span class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"> 4 </span>
    <span class="property-card__detail-text js-property-card-detail-text"> Quartos </span>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

spans = soup.select("li > span:nth-of-type(1)")
print(spans)
```

Prints first `<span>` directly under `<li>` tag:

```
[<span class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"> 3 </span>, <span class="property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value"> 4 </span>]
```

---

OR: Select `<span>` with `class="js-property-card-value"` under `<li>` tag:

```py
spans = soup.select("li > span.js-property-card-value")
print(spans)
```

OR (simplified, without `>` and `span`):

```py
spans = soup.select("li .js-property-card-value")
print(spans)
```